# sap.ui.unified.FileUploader change http methode / allow post on segw

Tags: file-upload, odata, sapui5, http-method

I am working on a file upload in UI5.
I can not use the `fileupload` via associations since I need the binary before writing in my table.

The problem is `sap.ui.unified.FileUploader` always uses the `POST` HTTP method, 
this causes an error in the backend system:

> `405 Methode not allowed`

I found this SAP Blog [FileUploader - 405 Method Not Allowed](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3838504) in which the problem is solved by extending the control and changing the HTTP method.

My question is there a more standard way to achieve that? I did not find any property in the control to configure the HTTP method.

Options:

- Maybe in the XHR Settings?
- Can you allow `POST` in `SEGW` or the user exit classes?

Comment: how do you mean that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the browser support of UI5.

Under the hood the file uploader is a `<div>` that contains a `<form>`.

The file can be uploaded either via *XMLHttpRequest* (XHR) or by simply submitting the form. Forms only support `GET` and `POST`.

If you want to use `PUT` **the first step** is setting `sendXHR="true"`.

But XHR does not work in IE9. For some reason the UI5 devs then decided:

> If IE9 cannot use `PUT` then no one should!

So **the second step** is to create a subclass of the FileUploader, add a new property for the HTTP method and overwrite the `_sendFilesWithXHR` method.  This is as standard as it gets ;)

Btw [this](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.unified/src/sap/ui/unified/FileUploader.js#L1357) is the line where they hardcoded `"POST"` which needs to be replaced with a dynamic call of the new property `httpMethod`.

Comment: you have to set sendXHR to true AND extend the control!

Comment: while it did solve my previous problem i now get the errer: 'The server is refusing to process the request because the entity has an unsupported format'

Answer (score 0):

Upload/Download with SEGW

- [Step by Step on how to use the SAPUI5 file upload feature](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/08/step-by-step-on-how-to-use-the-sapui5-file-upload-feature/)
- [File Upload/Download through NetWeaver Gateway](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/23/file-uploaddownload-through-netweaver-gateway/)
- [Uploading Files to SAP GW, Downloading Files from SAP GW – New Techniques](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/24/uploading-files-to-sap-gw-downloading-files-from-sap-gw-new-techniques/)
- Newest Blog!!: [Upload/download File in SAP UI5 Application using Gateway](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/08/uploaddownload-file-in-sap-ui5-application-using-gateway/)

Binary before Upload: only possible via Deffered & XHR

```
getBase64Promise: function (file) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function () {
                var encoded = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.*;base64,/, "");
                if ((encoded.length % 4) > 0) {
                    encoded += "=".repeat(4 - (encoded.length % 4));
                }
                resolve(encoded);
            };
            reader.onerror = function () {
                reject("error");
            };
        });
},


fileUploadChange: function (oControlEvent) {
        var that = this;
        var aFiles = oControlEvent.getParameters().files;
        var currentFile = aFiles[0];
        var sUrl = "yourNeeds..";
        this.getBase64Promise(currentFile).then(function (data) {
            that.xhrRequest(data, oView, sUrl);
        });
    },


xhrRequest: function (data, oView, url) {
        var oImage = "data:image/png;base64, " + data;
        oRequest = JSON.stringify(oImage);
        var xhrReadyStateChange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
                console.log("200", JSON.parse(this.response));
            }
        };

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", xhrReadyStateChange);
        xhr.open("POST", url, false); // setting request method & API endpoint, the last parameter is to set the calls as synchyronous
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); // adding request headers
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); // adding request headers
        xhr.send(oRequest); // sending request  
    }
});
```

Comment: just to see if i understood correctly: there is no functionallity in the framework to achieving what i want?

Comment: did you check the blog posts of my answer? I would expect that with SET_STREAM and GET_STREAM it should be possible also for associations ... check this link especially: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/08/step-by-step-on-how-to-use-the-sapui5-file-upload-feature/

Comment: check this blog from few days ago: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/08/uploaddownload-file-in-sap-ui5-application-using-gateway/